# Regex split fails at cyrillic string

Tags: python, regex, unicode, split

I need a simple and easy way to isolate words from strings of different languages. I know this is not a trivial task, but I just want to split on common punctuation like `.,;:?!@#`. Currently I'm using:

```
x = "this is sparta, or not."
print re.split([^-\w]', x)
['this', 'is', 'sparta', '', 'Or', 'not', '']
```

But, when I use a Cyrillic string:

```
x =  u'правил произношение суффиксов можно иногда'
w = re.split(r'[^-\w]', x)
```

I get:

```
[u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

How can I make a single generic splitter, which solves this problem? Thank you!

EDIT: The issue above is on Python 2.7.10.

Comment: I copy and paste your code and cannot reproduce your issue on python3.6

Comment: Hum... I'm on python 2.7.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.split(r'\W', x, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

It worked for me on 2.7.13.

Comment: That's it! Damn flags, thank you!

Comment: Will this work for Python 3 too?

Comment: Yes, but it will also work without specifying the flag, as Unicode is the default for Python3.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and past your code on Python3 console, everything works but when I try it on Python2.7 it had same issue as you got.

That's unicode issue.

```
x =  u'правил произношение суффиксов можно иногда'
myinput = raw_input(x.encode('utf8'))
w = re.split(r'[^-\w]', myinput)
```

Comment: raw_input? My console keeps waiting for me whan I use this.

Comment: >>> x =  u'правил произношение суффиксов можно иногда'
>>> myinput = raw_input(x.encode('utf8'))
правил произношение суффиксов можно иногда

Comment: @HaifengZhang Your answer is a bit misleading. You're simply passing x to raw_input as a prompt. The output of raw_input is of type str with utf-8 encoded (most probably but not certainly). Your answer certainly doesn't cover how to do it on unicode strings.